# CSS radial-gradient curve causes glitched one pixel box area

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

The expected result from the prototype:
[image]

My work (so far):

[image]

The problem:

[image]

1: There is a 1-pixel glitch border in the curvy area. It appears or disappears depending on website size, for example when the developer console is shown/hidden, changed its size, changed window size, or zoom in/out. How can I fix that?

2: The curve exists but it doesn't resemble the one from the prototype. How can I change the code to make the curve look more similar to the one from the prototype?

The code of the footer:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #3ab3da , #6858a2);">
            <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-md-4 p-0">
                    <div class="container h-50 d-flex align-items-center" style="background: white;">
                        <div class="row w-100">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 p-0">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-12 p-0">
                                <img class="img-fluid pb-3" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(25, "thumbnail")[0]; ?>" style="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="row h-25" style="background: white">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row h-25" style="background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,white 100.00%, transparent 100.00%) bottom right;">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row h-75">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="row h-25" style="background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 100.00%,white 100.00%) top left;">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row h-25">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row h-75">
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
                
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent_b" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent_b" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-uppercase fw-bold my-5" id="navbarSupportedContent_b" style="font-size: 24px;">
                                <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu([
                                        "menu"              => "Main menu",
                                        "container"         => "",
                                        "theme_location"    => "primary",
                                        "items_wrap"        => '<ul class="navbar-nav text-sm-center me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">%3$s</ul>'
                                    ]);
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-1 mb-5">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot mx-4"></i>xxx
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 border-start border-end">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-phone mx-4"></i> (+48) yyy
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-envelope mx-4"></i> zzz@zz.pl
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Live example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: linear-gradient(165deg, #3ab3da , #6858a2);">
                    <div class="row w-100">
                        <div class="col-md-4 p-0">
                            <div class="container h-50 d-flex align-items-center" style="background: white;">
                                <div class="row w-100">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 p-0">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-12 p-0">
                                        foto
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <div class="row h-25" style="background: white">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row h-25" style="background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,white 100.00%, transparent 100.00%) bottom right;">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row h-75">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="row h-25" style="background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 100.00%,white 100.00%) top left;">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row h-25">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row h-75">
                                <div class="col"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent_b" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent_b" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-uppercase fw-bold my-5" id="navbarSupportedContent_b" style="font-size: 24px;">
                                        <ul class="navbar-nav text-sm-center me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"><li class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-15 mx-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Strona główna</a></li>
<li class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-17 mx-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/towary/" aria-current="page">Sklep</a></li>
<li class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20 mx-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/o-nas/">O nas</a></li>
<li class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23 mx-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/kontakt/">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-1 mb-5">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot mx-4"></i>adres
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 border-start border-end">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-phone mx-4"></i> telefon
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <i class="fa-regular fa-envelope mx-4"></i> kontakt
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet which shows the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The spurious white line which comes and goes on zooming is caused by a sort of edge effect/rounding error when the system tries to map part CSS pixels to screen pixels.

Comment: Ok. I have added the snippet code. So how can I fix that line?